# How can I align COLs in a ROW with different heights to start from the top and not centered?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is how the problem looks visualized, the password col has a height of 173 but the email has no height and react somehow centers them. I don't know how to center them from the top so that they are vertically aligned

[Preview problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzQFq.png)

This is the code which makes the problems

```
<Row className="align-items-start">
<Col xs={4}>
    <OmisTextBox labeltext={t("Email")} name={"email"} placeholder={t("Email")} required />
</Col>
<Col xs={4}>
    <OmisPasswordArea labeltext={t("Password")} name={"password"} placeholder={t("Password")} autoComplete={'new-password'} ignoreempty={1} submitButtonDisabled={setSubmitButtonDisabled} />
    {/*<OmisPasswordTextBox labeltext={t("Password")} name={"password"} placeholder={t("Password")} autoComplete={'new-password'} />*/}
</Col>
```

I tried to do a
`className="align-items-start">`

or delete height (which doesnt work and I am not allowed to do,the height of 173 has to persist.

Comment: It appears as tho the inputs will have different heights depending on whether they are showing some validation errors. It would be helpful to know what the desired alignment is in all cases.
Are you able to share a mockup of the desired alignments. TIA.